# subsetting zip code strings differing length/characters in R, zip_choropleth

Tags: r, subset, choropleth

I am working with zip_choropleth. The issue stems that in my regions vector, there are some problem zip codes
These problems are:

1. strings with a space in them (especially those with the space at the start of the string)
2. Strings with a negative sign in them
3. Strings with letters in them

For example:

```
region
00234
78623
 3432
-0043
11000
HV 34
88302
```

What I would like to do is subset the data via df$region for strings of an exact length and only containing numbers. zip_choropleth does not seem to work otherwise.

I have tried subsetting via character length

```
data <- subset(data, nchar(data$region) == 5)
```

and via using grep to remove characters with "-" or " ". Neither method seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regular expression, you can match 5 digits:

```
> subset(df, grepl("\\d{5}", region))
  region
1  00234
2  78623
5  11000
8  88302
```

`\\d` means digits, and `{5}` means exactly five in a row.

You can also anchor the regex to the beginning/end using `^\\d{5}$` but that wasn't necessary with the sample data you posted.  You might want to try this eg if there are zipcodes with six or more digits in them, or zip codes with five digits and also letters.